# how to create an app with 360° view?

Tags: iphone, 3d

i want to show a box with 360 degrees view,such as like this function of this link (http://www.mathieusavard.info/threesixty/demo.html) written in jquery,and i want to do this function on iphone,but i do not know how to do it,so can anybody help me?thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Key frames first like this

http://www.articulate.com/rapid-elearning/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/keyframes-thumb.jpg[image]

All the images should be same size for instance 100 x 100
Name these images so you can use them while looping the name can be like animation1.png, animation2.png etc
On a [slider](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphonesliderexample.html) you can call this. 
So while the value is changing change images in your image view accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your answer,only this way to do it? do you have any other ways? the link demo i given does only tell you what i want to build,does there have 3D engine to do this function?